# What is the reason behind sealing data provider classes (like SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc.,) in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Why can't we inherit from the data provider classes (like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`) in ADO.NET?

Is there any reason behind that?

Comment: What is the reason why you want to inherit from those classes? One rule is composition over inheritance

Comment: [Why Are So Many Of The Framework Classes Sealed?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/22/why-are-so-many-of-the-framework-classes-sealed/) by Eric Lippert. I think there's also a similar vintage one where he expresses regret that `sealed` wasn't the default for C# (in much the same way that methods aren't `virtual` by default) but I cannot find it currently.

Comment: @SirRufo For Example, Take List class, it is not sealed. But, what makes these classes sealed?

Comment: Because the team that designed those classes decided to seal them. Why? Well, that's a question to ask them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks heaps for that link. Great content.

Comment: But I really do want to slap a Confusticator into the Froboznicator class!!

Answer (score 2):

I am reposting the content from the link in answer that @Damien_The_Unbeliever provided encase it ever goes down especially given that it is written by Eric Lippert.

> Why Are So Many Of The Framework Classes Sealed? 
> 22/01/2004 3 minutes to read
> I talked earlier this month about some issues in subclassing,
> and recommended sealing your classes. A Joel On Software reader asks
> why Microsoft ships so many sealed classes in the framework. The
> poster said: "I've yet to see a reasonable explanation about why they
> limited flexibility in such a way. "
>
> Well, every public class that my team produces is sealed if possible. 
> If it is not possible to seal a class then, if possible, it has an 
> inheritance demand on it so that only someone with the MSFT private 
> key can subclass it. My reasons for insisting upon this policy boil 
> down to one overriding principle:
>
> Good code does exactly what it was designed to do, no more, no less.
>
> Let me expand upon that in four ways.
>
> 1. Philosophical. OOP design includes subclassing to represent the 
>    polymorphic "is a" relationship between two things. A Giraffe IS AN 
>    Ungulate IS A Mammal IS AN Animal... Unless I can think of a clear 
>    case where a customer would need to express an IS A relationship with 
>    some code that I produce, I don't allow for such cases.
> 2. Practical. Designing classes so that they can be effectively 
>    extended by third parties is HARD. (Look at the collection base 
>    classes for example.) You have to get the design right -- what is 
>    protected? You have to implement that design correctly. The test 
>    matrix grows enormously because you have to think about what weird 
>    things people are going to do. You have to document the protected 
>    methods and write documentation on how to properly subclass the thing.
>
> This is all expensive and time consuming -- that is time that we could 
> be spending looking for bugs in more important user scenarios, 
> planning future versions, fixing security holes, whatever. There is 
> only a finite amount of developer time we can spend on designing and 
> implementing code, so we have to spend it the way that benefits 
> customers most. If the class is not designed to be extended, I'm going 
> to avoid all that expense by sealing it. I am not going to release 
> half-baked classes that look extensible but in fact are not quite 
> there.
>
> 3. Compatible. If in the future I discover that I should have sealed a 
>    class, I'm stuck. Sealing a class is a breaking change. If I discover 
>    that I should have left a class unsealed, unsealing in a future 
>    version is a non-breaking change. Sealing classes helps maintain 
>    compatibility.
> 4. Secure. the whole point of polymorphism is that you can pass around 
>    objects that look like Animals but are in fact Giraffes. There are 
>    potential security issues here.
>
> Every time you implement a method which takes an instance of an 
> unsealed type, you MUST write that method to be robust in the face of 
> potentially hostile instances of that type. You cannot rely upon any 
> invariants which you know to be true of YOUR implementations, because 
> some hostile web page might subclass your implementation, override the 
> virtual methods to do stuff that messes up your logic, and passes it 
> in. Every time I seal a class, I can write methods that use that class 
> with the confidence that I know what that class does.
>
> Now, I recognize that developers are highly practical people who just 
> want to get stuff done. Being able to extend any class is convenient, 
> sure. Typical developers say "IS-A-SHMIZ-A, I just want to slap a 
> Confusticator into the Froboznicator class". That developer could 
> write up a hash table to map one to the other, but then you have to 
> worry about when to remove the items, etc, etc, etc -- it's not rocket 
> science, but it is work.
>
> Obviously there is a tradeoff here. The tradeoff is between letting 
> developers save a little time by allowing them to treat any old object 
> as a property bag on the one hand, and developing a well-designed, 
> OOPtacular, fully-featured, robust, secure, predictable, testable 
> framework in a reasonable amount of time -- and I'm going to lean 
> heavily towards the latter. Because you know what? Those same 
> developers are going to complain bitterly if the framework we give 
> them slows them down because it is half-baked, brittle, insecure, and 
> not fully tested!